# Octave Equivalent of Python Optparse / getopt

Tags: octave

Is there an octave Equivalent of Python Optparse / getopt?

Something like:

```
[parsed_args, remaining] = optparse(argv());
```

I run octave scripts from command line.

```
./foo.m -p lease -g ive -m e -o ptparse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv()` will return the command line arguments passed to Octave as a string cell array. It should be straightforward to proceed with this cell array. Could you be more specific of the `optparse()` functionality needed. What operating system you are running on?